# Flutter & Dart, pub.dev uploading a package, why license link isn't highlighted?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, flutter-packages, dart-packages

[Screenshoot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cJpp.png)

[Screenshoot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GQyb.png)

Take a look at the first screenshoot. The "LICENSE" word isn't highlighted, and that is my trouble. If I click it, nothing happens. Other packages, see screenshoot 2, don't have this issue. The license link for them works correctly.

Thank you for your help!

Package link:
https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_text_highlighting

Comment: Could you link to the package in question so we can actually help you?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/dynamic_text_highlighting#dynamic-text-highlighting-dth

Comment: I have also noticed that not only the mine has this problem...

Comment: Maybe create a bug here: https://github.com/dart-lang/pub-dev/issues

Comment: I have just done it, thank you for the advice 